add repo to debian (gpg issue)
First, I have done literally hours of work and research on this... attempting to find a solution my self. But I am unable to either understand what I am missing or get all the info I need (not sure which). Second, this is the first time I have ever dealt with GPG. Lastly, I am aware just how old the version of Zabbix am trying to get is.
I am setting up a server and want to monitor some items using Zabbix (sender only). I am trying to "properly" add Zabbix as a repo so I can install the "zabbix-sender" using apt-get. Below is (to the best of my ability) everything I have tried / learned on how this is done. Going to skip to where I am instead of explaining where I started (not knowing anything).

Get public key wget https://repo.zabbix.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-ZABBIX-79EA5ED4
Import key gpg --import RPM-GPG-KEY-ZABBIX-79EA5ED4
Sign key gpg --lsign-key 79EA5ED4
Trust key gpg --edit-key 79EA5ED4

trust
4
quit


Put repo key in key ring curl -fsSL https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.4/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/zabbix.gpg
Add repo to sources list echo deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/zabbix.gpg] http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.4/debian jessie main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zabbix.list
Update repos apt-get update

Result
Err:1 http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.4/debian jessie InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D13D58E479EA5ED4
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.4/debian jessie InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D13D58E479EA5ED4

Result of gpg --list-keys
gpg: checking the trustdb
gpg: marginals needed: 3  completes needed: 1  trust model: pgp
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   1  signed:   1  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u
gpg: depth: 1  valid:   1  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 1f, 0u
gpg: next trustdb check due at 2026-05-03
/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
------------------------
pub   rsa3072 2024-05-03 [SC] [expires: 2026-05-03]
      REDACTED for security
uid           [ultimate] REDACTED for security (this is my key)
sub   rsa3072 2024-05-03 [E] [expires: 2026-05-03]

pub   dsa1024 2012-10-28 [SC]
      FBABD5FB20255ECAB22EE194D13D58E479EA5ED4
uid           [  full  ] Zabbix SIA <packager@zabbix.com>
sub   elg1024 2012-10-28 [E]

What am I doing wrong?

I tried your suggestion Stephen. Unfortunately, that resulted in the same error.
I asked someone I know about this... He pointed out that the GPG key that I am getting is expired... I believe that may be the actual cause. I was confused by the wording of the error "the public key is not available". This led me to believe that apt could not find my imported key. I believe now that what this actually means is that it could not find a valid key for it.
I am giving up on getting this specific version. I am hoping that the current version of zabbix-sender has not changed enough to make it so that I will be unable to use it to report to the server I intend to (an old server set up by my boss).

Steps 1 through 5 are messed up; all you need to do is download the key:
wget https://repo.zabbix.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-ZABBIX-79EA5ED4
sudo mv RPM-GPG-KEY-ZABBIX-79EA5ED4 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/zabbix.gpg

Adjust the path to match in step 6, and step 7 should now work.
